# Copy and pasting header files in to main.cpp produces redefinition error

Tags: c++, mingw, c-preprocessor, c++14

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(){

    return -2;

}
```

When I compile this, there is no error. If I swap the positions of `#include <curses.h>` and `#include <Windows.h>` then I get an error that `MOUSE_MOVED` is redefined (once in `curses.h` and the other in `wincon.h` - which is included by `Windows.h`). I'm guessing that `wincon.h` has a line similar to:

```
#ifndef MOUSE_MOVED
#define MOUSE_MOVED 2
#endif
```

but curses.h does not, which is why it depends on which way the include directives are ordered. On the other hand, having a look through `wincon.h` I couldn't see such a conditional statement, but I find it's pretty hard to keep track of what's being defined in header files when there are few comments.

My main concern though, is that when `curses.h` is included before `Windows.h`, it compiles fine. To see why this might be, I copied and pasted all of the contents of `curses.h` and put it in the same location as `#include <curses.h>`, I did the same with `Windows.h` and then `wincon.h`. Surprisingly to me, this brought back the error with `MOUSE_MOVED` again. All I did was copy and paste the contents of the headers, is this not what the preprocessor does anyway? Just replace the include directives with the contents of the header? Why would doing such a thing bring back the error? (MinGW g++ 6.1.0)

(I can't paste all of the contents of curses.h and Windows.h, but [a small download for curses can be found here](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) if needed)

Comment: I'm not going to lie - the title made me laugh - "copy and paste produced redefinition error".

Comment: @UKMonkey aka _breaking the odr for fun and profit_.

Comment: There may be special pragmas that only work when `#include`'d, or perhaps the compiler considers `Windows.h` a system header and suppresses some warnings/errors inside it. Hard to tell without testing.

Comment: @skypjack Well, technically, ODR doesn't apply to macros...

Comment: @T.C. Right, but from the title I got it as _the whole header file_. ;-)

Comment: What is your question exactly? If you just want to fix the problem when the includes are in the other order, do `#undef MOUSE_MOVED` after including windows.h  (and make sure you didn't include any WinAPI code that expects the windows version of that macro)